# Understanding function endpoints

Tags: r, xts, endpoints, dayofmonth

I have a time series of returns. In the first column I have all my dates. With this function (searching for hours) I finally managed to get the first value of every month.

The problem was, that not always day 1 is the first value. Sometimes it is day 2,3,4,5 etc.

Luckily with this function it all works:

```
library(xts)
month<- data[,1] ## all my dates    
first.values <- month[head(endpoints(month, "months") + 1, -1)]
```

What I want to understand though: Why the +1 and -1? That is all I would like to understand.

I am not satisfied that the code works, I really want to understand.  Unfortunately I do not have enough reputation to contact or comment someone (since I found this code here).

Comment: You might want to mention what programming language this is.

Comment: Sorry! It is R- statistics software.

Comment: Also, `endpoints` is not a base R function, so you should include the name of any packages you are using. If you found this code on SO, you should provide a link to that post in the body of your question. For `head`, the -1 says return all values of the vector/data.frame/matrix except the final value. See the help page `?head` for more details. By the way, when coding, I typically spend 20% of my time (or more) looking at the help files of functions to better understand how they work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's prepare sample data :

```
month <- seq.Date(from=Sys.Date()-5,to=Sys.Date()+10,by="day")

# [1] "2018-06-18" "2018-06-19" "2018-06-20" "2018-06-21" "2018-06-22" "2018-06-23" "2018-06-24" "2018-06-25" "2018-06-26"
# [10] "2018-06-27" "2018-06-28" "2018-06-29" "2018-06-30" "2018-07-01" "2018-07-02" "2018-07-03"
```

`xts::endpoints` gives the index of the last observation of each month, always beginning with 0:

```
library(xts)
endpoints(month, "months") 
# [1]  0 13 16
```

So if you add `1`, you'll have the index of the first available day of the next month and conveniently, the 0 will be the index of the 1st day of the 1st month:

```
endpoints(month, "months") + 1
# [1]  1 14 17
```

The last value is meaningless though, so we drop it:

```
head(endpoints(month, "months") + 1, -1)
# [1]  1 14
```

And we end up with your solution:

```
first.values <- month[head(endpoints(month, "months") + 1, -1)]
# [1] "2018-06-18" "2018-07-01"
```

An alternate way of doing it:

```
month <- as.xts(month)
first_as_list <- lapply(split(month,f="month"), function(x) index(x)[1])
do.call(c,first_as_list)
# [1] "2018-06-18" "2018-07-01"
```

Comment: Thank you a lot Moody_Mudskipper! I appreciate you took the time for such a detailed answer. :)

Comment: You're welcome, I added an alternate way to compute it, that you might find more intuitive. Consider marking the question accepted if it solved your issue.

Comment: @J.Pop: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).